# I need to fetch all the numbers between 2 spaces after my expression

Tags: regex

I would like to extract data from the below sample data using **regex**

I have tried **\d{2}/\d{4}** and get the ex: **39/2021**.I need to get **23** which is in between 2 spaces. Any numbers between those 2 spaces after **my expression**.

### Sample Data

```
Backlog 25 567 07/2022 120 2510
39/2021 23 590 08/2022 120 2630
40/2021 120 710 09/2022 120 2750
41/2021 120 830 10/2022 120 2870
42/2021 120 950 11/2022 120 2990
45/2021 120 1070 12/2022 120 3110
47/2021 120 1190 13/2022 120 3230
48/2021 120 1310 14/2022 240 3470
49/2021 120 1430 15/2022 120 3590
50/2021 120 1550 16/2022 120 3710
51/2021 120 1670 17/2022 240 3950
52/2021 120 1790 18/2022 120 4070
02/2022 120 1910 19/2022 120 4190
03/2022 120 2030 20/2022 120 4310
04/2022 120 2150 21/2022 240 4550
05/2022 120 2270 22/2022 120 4670
06/2022 120 2390 23/2022 120 4790
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4RRd.png)

I have added a picture reference for the output.

Comment: Why don't you capture them? `\d{2}\/\d{4}\s+(\d+)`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/2P2biN/1). `(?<=\d{2}\/\d{4}\s)\d+` [might](https://regex101.com/r/2P2biN/2) also be enough. Also, `\d{2}\/\d{4}\s+\K\d+` [has proven](https://regex101.com/r/2P2biN/3) a lot of times. See [the SO search  results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bregex%5d%20number%20after%20string), this is a very common question here.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a number after string, it is digits between spaces after matching `\d{2}/\d{4}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group, matching a space before the digits and either assert a whitespace boundary after it or match the following space

```
\b\d{2}/\d{4} (\d+)(?!\S)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d{2}/\d{4}` Match 2 digits `/` 4 digits
- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in group 1
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQuejo/1)

If there should be a space at the left and at the right:

`\b\d{2}/\d{4} (\d+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RKcvuY/1)